# “there are other worlds than these.” vs "there are worlds other than these"

Tags: american-english

There is this phrase from a Stephen King's book ([source](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/13466-go-then-there-are-other-worlds-than-these)):

> “Go then, there are other worlds than these.”

To me, this phrase sounds like it's wrong, and the correct version (in terms of grammar) seems to be "there are worlds other than these".

"**Other than**" is very common.

My question is: which of these phrases are right? Are both of them right, or just the original one, or just the one I suggested?

Comment: King's usage is felicitous and deliberately lyrical. Yours is fine as well, of course. But so you know, usage governs grammar, and not vice versa, and it is exactly by widespread use that a construction becomes grammatical, and having extremely widely-read authors definitely bolsters a construction's popularity. In general, if a famous and widely-regarded, not to mention native-speaking English author employs some construction, you can trust he not only has command of the language but also his craft.

Comment: These both appear perfectly standard to me.